# Connecting Sharepoint lists via lookup/utilizing the lookup item in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, lookup-column, dropdown

I'm making a leave request where the user picks which department he/she is in and also their manager to send the request to. I don't want the user to manually type anyone's email address. I want a drop down column of 'Department' and a dropdown column of 'Managers'. See the photo. I already made these dropdown columns, and they are taking information from the same list. Thing is, I want so that whichever Department they pick, it only shows the managers of THAT department. For example, in the photo they selected 'Engineering'. In the column Manager it is showing all 4 managers but I only want the manager of the Department to be seen. Reza is the manager of Engineering so I only want his name shown, no one elses. If you need any more info let me know. I am new to this and do not know much of the jargon, or if I am missing a key detail in order to recieve help. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
Thanks to the first person that replied. As you said, I created Department as a Lookup column and select Manager as an additional column. However, I am still getting a drop down of ALL the managers. Is there some secret setting I have to enable. I am at a lost of what I'm doing wrong...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a look into this [article](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-a-lookup-column-in-sharepoint/) showing how to create **Lookup** column and show additional columns. In your case, you need to create **Department** as a Lookup column and select **Manager** as an additional column. When users selected a Department, **corresponding** manager will be picked/showed in your list

Comment: Your Department and Manager columns/fields are in the same list, that's **Group Department** list, so you don't need another **Supervisor** column to enter a manager. In the data entry form, when you select a Department, the corresponding Manger should already be selected. Cascading dropdowns are different, and based on at least two distinct lookup columns pointing to two different lookup lists linked on a common key

Comment: My mistake on leaving out this small detail...some departments have more than one manager. So if a user selects the department IT, the next column is a dropdown of the managers of IT, which in this case is two people. Finance has 3 managers as well. This cascading dropdown might be the solution so I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a Cascading dropdown (where one dropdown filters the values of another). This is not supported using the out of the box customizations within the modern list form. You'll need to customize the list form with Power Apps.

Here's a video that demonstrates how to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzvMbmb5pmo

Comment: This was the option I was looking for. Many Thanks!